# How to Create ASP.NET Registration Page

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am currently using Web Matrix to create a Hotel Booking website. I have had some prior expereince using Visual Studio 2010, but changed to Web Matrix as it seems to have quite a lot of information online. Following a tutorial on W3Schools to help me get the website started I have completed the tutorial but my registration page seems to have some sort of error.

This is following code:

```
    @{Layout = "Layout.cshtml";

// Initialize page
var email = "";
var password = "";
var confirmPassword = "";
var ErrorMessage = "";

// If this is a POST request, validate and process data
if (IsPost)
{
  email = Request.Form["email"];
  password = Request.Form["password"];
  confirmPassword = Request.Form["confirmPassword"];

  if (email.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty()) 
  {ErrorMessage = "You must specify both email and password.";}

  if (password != confirmPassword)
  {ErrorMessage = "Password and confirmation do not match.";}

  // If all information is valid, create a new account
  if (ErrorMessage=="")
    { 
    var db = Database.Open("Users");
    var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile 
    WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
    if (user == null)
      {
      db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);
      WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, false);
      // Navigate back to the homepage and exit
      Response.Redirect("Default.cshtml");
      }
      else
      {ErrorMessage = "Email address is already in use.";}
    }
}

if (ErrorMessage!="")
{
<p>@ErrorMessage</p> 
<p>Please correct the errors and try again.</p>
}

}

<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
<ol>
<li>
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
</li>
<li>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
</li>
<li>
<label>Confirm Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" />
</li>
<li>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register" /></p>
</li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the corresponding part of the tutorial, [W3School ASP.NET Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/website/webpages_login.asp)

Any other useful information or tutorials that I could follow to get this system well in to development feel free to share, deadline for testing phase isn't so far away.

Thanks!

Comment: "my registration page seems to have some sort of error." The error being what, exactly?

Comment: `Source Error: 


Line 25:     var db = Database.Open("Users");
Line 26:     var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile 
Line 27:     WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
Line 28:     if (user == null)
Line 29:       {

Source File: /Register.cshtml    Line: 27 ` Thanks!